Adding Routes to Python Flask e2e tests with pytest-flask live_server
I want to access an endpoint added via @live_server.app.route with playwright, but I can only access it via test_client.
I have two fixtures:
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def e2e_server(live_server):
    @live_server.app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
    def get_frontend():
        return "Test 1234", 200

    live_server.start()
    yield live_server


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def chrome_browser(e2e_server):
    with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        context = browser.new_context()
        yield context

    context.close()
    browser.close()

And then I have two tests, the test_frontend works but accesing the same route with playwright gives a 404.
Accessing a route that is in part of my normal app works fine.
def test_frontend(e2e_server, client):
    res = client.get(f"{e2e_server.url()}/")
    assert res.status_code == 200
    print(res.data)   # Works as expected

def test_e2e_local(e2e_server, chrome_browser):
    page = chrome_browser.new_page()
    page.goto(e2e_server.url()) # Returns 404

Right now I have a working workaround, but I would like to replace it with the solution above
workaround:
    if "test_e2e" in os.getenv("PYTEST_CURRENT_TEST", ""):
       # add testing endpoint

